# unable to create users on OpenLDAP having german umlauts

Tags: openldap

When I try to add a user on OpenLDAP 2.4.32 using ldapmodify which has a german umlaut I get a ldap syntax error

```
ldapmodify.exe" -a -x -H ldap://localhost -D %LDAP_ROOT% -w %LDAP_SECRET%
dn:uid=aöich,ou=Users,dc=cricbox,dc=in
changetype: add
objectClass:person
objectClass:inetOrgPerson
objectClass:organizationalPerson
uid:aöich
cn:aöich
sn:aöich

ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: invalid DN
```

How to add a user with german mmlaut character on OpenLDAP server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your databank schema supports Unicode. Check [LDAP documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin23/schema.html) here:

```
  attributeType ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name'
                DESC 'name(s) associated with the object'
                EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
                SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
                SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )
        attributeType ( 2.5.4.3 NAME ( 'cn' 'commonName' )
                DESC 'common name(s) assciated with the object'
                SUP name )
```

Your attributes should contain:

```
 directoryString    1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15   Unicode (UTF-8) string
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Yes My schema supports above Unicode as I am able to add users with Japanese and Chinese characters,But I am unable to add German umlauts. Any specific conversion problem ?

Comment: I got to know that when the users with german umlaut characters are added to LDAP server they are converted to base64 decoded strings Eg:  "dn::base64 value",What I tried is converting user dn from utf8 without BOM to ANSI and storing it,still unsure whether this will work.

Comment: Why not store every user name in base64? Converting can cause you a lot of headache later, because you can loose data going from base64 to str and back (just like int(6.6) != float(int(6.6)) can cause data lose)

Comment: Thanks, will try to store in base64